# Python list of lists comparison

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have two lists of the following type:

```
A=[[a1,b1,c1],[d1,e1,f1]]
B=[[a2,b1,c2],[d2,e1,f2]]
```

I want to be able to generate a list C like this:

```
C=[[a1,b1,c1,a2,c2],[d1,e1,f1,d2,f2]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So what have you tried? SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @BhargavRao SO seems to be a coding service - two answers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution does not require sorting nor indexes

```
C = [ea+[e for e in eb if e not in ea] for ea,eb in zip(A,B)]
```

it produces

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'c2'], ['d1', 'e1', 'f1', 'd2', 'f2']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use `zip()` function to get the columns and then use `collections.OrderedDict` preserve the unique elements with the previous order :

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> [d.fromkeys(i+j).keys() for i,j in zip(A,B)]
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'c2'], ['d1', 'e1', 'f1', 'd2', 'f2']]
```

Comment: interesting solution, as usual. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As an list comprehension:

```
import operator
c = [sorted(list(set(a + b)), key=operator.itemgetter(1, 0)) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

Or as a loop:

```
import operator
results = []
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    uniques = list(set(a + b))
    # Here we do two sorts in one call:
    results.append(sorted(uniques, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 0)))

print(results)
```

> `[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'c2'], ['d1', 'e1', 'f1', 'd2', 'f2']]`

Answer (score 0):

```
C = []
# zip the lists to be able to loop through both
# at the same time.
# make from A and B sets to be able to make a union of 
# A and B. Convert the union set to list to sort it and
# to append to the main list
for i, (m, n) in enumerate(zip(A,B)):
  C.append(sorted(list(set(A[i]) | set(B[i]))))

 print(C)

**output**

[['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'c1', 'c2'], ['d1', 'd2', 'e1', 'f1', 'f2']]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.